# Cannot find declaration of element handler-chains Jboss Developer Studio

Tags: xml, jboss, xsd

I have a handler-chain configuration for my `Webservice` handler

At my `Webservice` class I have;

```
 @HandlerChain(file = "jaxws-handlers-server.xml")
    public class RoleMemberServiceSoap11Impl{...}
```

and my jaxws-handlers-server.xml is ;

```
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <handler-chain>
        <protocol-bindings>##SOAP11_HTTP</protocol-bindings>
        <handler>
            <handler-name>TransactionBridgeHandler</handler-name>
            <handler-class>org.jboss.jbossts.txbridge.inbound.JaxWSTxInboundBridgeHandler
            </handler-class>
        </handler>
        <handler>
            <handler-class>com.arjuna.mw.wst11.service.JaxWSHeaderContextProcessor
            </handler-class>
        </handler>
    </handler-chain>
</handler-chains>
```

In that `xml` file i got the following error for   element.

```
Cannot find declaration of element handler-chains
```

I ve searched and tried various workaround about changing xmlns:xsd urls. Also I tried the workaround  that given at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-17859

but that does not help.

`IDE :  Jboss Developer Studio.`

Project:  Dynamic Web Project 2.4

Server Jboss 6.1+

Java : 1.6

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I resolved the issue by replacing

```
 <handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

to

```
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_web_services_metadata_handler_2_0.xsd">
```

Comment: namespace 'jaxb' seem unnecessary in this situation. It works even without

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem in Eclipse + JDK 1.8 that was resolved by changing the address of the XMLNS attribute.

**From:**

```
<javaee:handler-chains xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

**To:**

```
<javaee:handler-chains xmlns:javaee="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

**See the link below that Oracle has changed the address of the new schemas:**
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html#7

Comment: @Tunceren example worked for me in Red Hat Jboss Developer 10.2 (Eclipse) and JDK 1.8.  Sorry didnt get to try your example.

Comment: +1 for the link to javaee; please consider that the issue in quite well discussed in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-17859 and the solution that works for me with JDK 1.8 JEE7 is the one from @Jason Glass ( 2017-10-31):  ```<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_web_services_metadata_handler_2_0.xsd">```

Comment: [javaee_web_services_metadata_handler_2_0.xsd](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_web_services_metadata_handler_2_0.xsd) which defines `javaee:handler-chains` is an old schema
(released 2007-11-21 according to http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/)
and it uses the old namespace http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
(not the new http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my solution help someone. I just change

```
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
```

to

```
<handler-chains xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
```